# Xbim Geometry error

Tags: c#, geometry, ifc, xbim

I am using the following C# code to access geometry data from an ifc4 file. The file contains only a wall created using Revit 2016. I am using Xbim library. This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly ILog logger =
       LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
    static string _ifcFile = @"C:\Examples\OneWall.ifc";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BasicConfigurator.Configure();

        IfcStore model = IfcStore.Open(_ifcFile);
        Xbim3DModelContext context = new Xbim3DModelContext(model);
        context.CreateContext();
        XbimMeshGeometry3D mesh = mesh = (XbimMeshGeometry3D)context.ShapeGeometryMeshOf(context.ShapeInstances().FirstOrDefault());

        //The rest of my code
    }
}
```

I get the following error. I am using visual studio 2015.

1226 [1] DEBUG Xbim.Geometry.Engine.Interop.XbimCustomAssemblyResolver (null) - Loading assembly from: C:\Examples\ifcWall\ifcWall\bin\Debug\x86\Xbim.Geometry.Engine32.dll
1404 [1] DEBUG Xbim.Geometry.Engine.Interop.XbimCustomAssemblyResolver (null) - Loading assembly from: C:\Examples\ifcWall\ifcWall\bin\Debug\x86\Xbim.Geometry.Engine32.dll

Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Invalid Geometry Command
   at Xbim.ModelGeometry.Scene.XbimMeshGeometry3D.Read(String data, Nullable`1 trans) in c:\BuildAgent\work\860c3b913b6c647f\Xbim.ModelGeometry.Scene\XbimMeshGeometry3D.cs:line 219
   at Xbim.ModelGeometry.Scene.XbimMeshGeometry3D.Add(String mesh, Int16 productTypeId, Int32 productLabel, Int32 geometryLabel, Nullable`1 transform, Int16 modelId) in c:\BuildAgent\work\860c3b913b6c647f\Xbim.ModelGeometry.Scene\XbimMeshGeometry3D.cs:line 669
   at Xbim.ModelGeometry.Scene.Xbim3DModelContext.ShapeGeometryMeshOf(XbimShapeInstance shapeInstance) in c:\BuildAgent\work\860c3b913b6c647f\Xbim.ModelGeometry.Scene\Xbim3DModelContext.cs:line 1525
   at ifcWall.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\karshenas\Documents\Courses\CEEN6840\VS_Projects\ifcWall\ifcWall\Program.cs:line 26

Any help to fix the error is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You run into an area where API has changed and this particular functions expects data in a different format. If what you need is a triangulation of the shape this code should work for you:

```
using System.IO;
using Xbim.Common.Geometry;
using Xbim.Ifc;
using Xbim.ModelGeometry.Scene;
using Xbim.Common.XbimExtensions;

namespace CreateWexBIM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string file = @"4walls1floorSite.ifc";

            var model = IfcStore.Open(file);
            var context = new Xbim3DModelContext(model);
            context.CreateContext();

            var instances = context.ShapeInstances();
            foreach (var instance in instances)
            {
                var geometry = context.ShapeGeometry(instance);
                var data = ((IXbimShapeGeometryData)geometry).ShapeData;
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                    {
                        var mesh = reader.ReadShapeTriangulation();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The best is to ask in [xBIM GitHub Issues](https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimGeometry/issues) and to share the file. IFC geometry can get very complex so it is not possible to really answer your question just based on the exception.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. Once you have [enough rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) you'll be able to add comments to the question.

Comment: Edited the answer to provide actual solution.